# Is it safe to use a deinit inside a @StateObject as a signal that a SwiftUI view's lifetime has ended?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, there's no way (that I know of) to perform some action once a view's lifetime has ended. `.onDisappear(perform:)` does not work, because it can be called multiple times during the lifetime, there's no way of knowing if it's going to be the last time.

The only thing I can think of is using the deinitializer of an `ObservableObject`.

`@StateObject`s are tied to the view's lifetime and therefere deinitialized some time *after* that lifetime has ended (not necessarily immediately, but that's fine).

Here's an example:

```swift
struct ViewLifetimeHelper: View {
    @StateObject private var lifetimeViewModel: LifetimeViewModel

    init(
        onInit: @escaping () async -> Void,
        onDeinit: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        _lifetimeViewModel = .init(
            wrappedValue: .init(
                onInit: onInit,
                onDeinit: onDeinit
            )
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
    }
}

private final class LifetimeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private let task: Task<Void, Never>

    @MainActor var onInit: () async -> Void
    @MainActor var onDeinit: () -> Void

    @MainActor init(
        onInit: @escaping () async -> Void,
        onDeinit: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        self.onInit = onInit
        self.onDeinit = onDeinit

        task = Task {
            await onInit()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        task.cancel()
        onDeinit()
    }

}
```

I could then place this `ViewLifetimeHelper` view as an invisible background to any view and populate the `onInit` and `onDeinit` closures to react to the start and end of the lifetime of a view. This does appear to work perfectly fine.

But are there any limitations or consequences for this? Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the point of Combine's `ObservableObject` when used with `@StateObject` is the Combine pipeline is created at object init and torn down on deinit. You need to use `.assign` and `@Published` for this to work correctly.

Since it looks to me you are trying to use async/await you should not use Combine's `ObservableObject` and instead use the `.task` or `.task(id:)` modifier in the View struct. The task will be started when the UIViews appear that are described by the `View` struct, cancelled when they disappear and cancelled/restarted if the `id` param changes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure what you mean with `.assign` in this case. What do I need to assign? 

But yeah, I'd prefer using Concurrency.  Unfortunately, `.task` is also cancelled and restarted multiple times. For example, when you push a new `view` onto a navigation stack. That cancels all tasks in the disappearing view.

Comment: .assign is the Combine operator that is used in ObservableObject but since your aim is async/await as I said you shouldn't use Combine at all. You can place the async/await .task(id:) modifier anywhere in the View hierarchy sounds to me like you need to move it up.

Comment: Yeah, I know what `.assign` is but I'm not sure how I'd have to use it to trigger a closure call when the view's lifetime ends. And yes, `.task(id:)` can be placed in the view, but it is cancelled multiple times, not only when the view lifetime ends. So it's not working in this case, unfortunately

Comment: When you use .assign the pipeline is torn down on ObservableObject deinit automatically.

Comment: It might work with `task` place outside a given navigationView, but that would be quite a limitation

Comment: Ah, now I get what you mean! Yeah, that could work, indeed. But I'd rather not use Combine, but maybe it's the most sensible thing to do.

Comment: Ah, I don't think using `.assign` works. If we add a subscriber in the view and the view disappear, it will never receive the "final" signal and if we subscribe to it in the `ObservableObject`, there's either a reference cylce or, if we capture `weak self`, self will already be `nil` when the object has deinitialized

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/assign(to:)

Comment: What I've been trying to say is if you are using async/await you shouldn't use Combine's ObservableObject at all. Did you know ObservableObject is part of Combine?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of using `.assign` to solve this problem? And yes, I know `ObservableObject` is part of Combine, but it's also used as the protocol required for having reference types as state in SwiftUI